# Is there a way to make the text of a video SEO / browser find friendly?

Tags: video, seo

One thing that's always annoyed me about videos (especially tutorial videos) is that you can't search the content, either in your browser or on a search engine.

Now granted people have full transcripts of videos, but these do not work like reading a document where you can search for the text and then continue reading it where you found it, before and after.   The equivalent in a video would have to be something like searching for the text and then having the text associated with a particular time point in a video.  Close captioning does this to a point.

Are there any tools / APIs for proper ways of making the content of a video searchable using a search engine or the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment your transcript is visible in your webpages source code, Google bots find it, read it, you get the SEO credit for it so you **can** search the transcript content with a search engine.

Suggestions:

- use HTML5 tags and include transcript.
- use [Schema video object](http://schema.org/VideoObject) notation.
- Include transcript using VTT file

Check [this](http://www.3playmedia.com/2013/03/06/video-seo-series-5-seo-strategies-publishing-short-form-video-transcripts-captions/) link for video SEO.