# Do search engines index audio files?

Tags: seo

I have 1000+ hours of e-education audio. If these are in  tags on separate pages of my website, will search engines recognize the text said in the audio files, or do I have to add a transcription instead? Could this transcription be between the  and  tags, or does it look like I'm hiding information from the visitor for SEO purposes?
What is the best way to get these e-learning classes indexed?

Comment: Similar question about video: [Is there a way to make the text of a video SEO / browser find friendly?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82520/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-text-of-a-video-seo-browser-find-friendly)

Comment: The only answer I've ever seen to this is similar to @StephenOstermiller link.  However, I've wondered why wouldn't Google be able to do this?  They transcribe YouTube videos automatically.

Comment: Google doesn't transcribe audio files. I don't think they're indexed at all (unless they're videos). I'd recommend adding a transcription of your own as textual content on the page.

Answer (score 2):

As no one has answered, hopefully this partial answer

I don't think it is explicitly stated by Google, but the  weight of evidence from the SEO community, and from the results of Google voice recognition for subtitles in Youtube (which it owns) is that Google does recognise the text in audio files - this is relatively recent though (see https://blog.hotmart.com/en/audio-seo/).  There is speculation that the word "Podcast" needs to be used if people are searching for the audio though, so it may be of limited benefit. (https://www.impactplus.com/blog/3-facts-you-need-to-know-about-google-indexing-spoken-words-within-podcasts is an interesting read)

Putting information between tags would not generally be considered hiding information from visitors for SEO purposes - and indeed there are whole Schemas advocated by Google which are not displayed to casual visitors.   I'm believe Google is more worried about showing different content to "real" visitors the to their bot.